# Tag library descriptor file for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can we add a Tag library descriptor file(`.tld` file) in `AngularJS`(in HTML page)

I have tried using `taglib` tag

```
<%@ taglib prefix="his" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/xyz.tld" prefix="sample"%>
```

but in HTML page it's giving a warning as

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- Invalid text string ( 
<%@ taglib prefix="his" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/xyz.tld" prefix="sample"%>
}
```

Comment: This is jsp taglib descriptop, not related with angularjs